# how to format the data inside the DataGridTemplateColumn in datagrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0

this  is my xaml code where i have  2  fields  placed under one  template  column.

now i am getting the format the output like this so that i can specify the space betweeen these 2  columns

```
    Color

red        image1

green     image2

green     image2

white     image6
```

so that  output looks  good.

How can  i define space  between them  so that it looks  like the above  one

right now thw output is like this

```
    color

    Redimage1

    greenimage2

    greenimage2

    whiteimage6
```

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Color" Width="80">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Loaded ="StackPanel_Loaded" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue"></TextBlock>
                <Image x:Name="imgTargetScore" Source ="{Binding ColorImage}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch ="Fill"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

loking forward for an  solution

thanks in advance

prince

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a bit of `Margin` on your TextBlock and/or Image controls:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" Margin="0,0,5,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue" />
```

This example puts a 5px margin on the right edge of the TextBlock. If you want your images to line up vertically then you may want to also make the TextBlock a set width, by default it is only as long as the text in it.